# FTP domain indexed by google

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt, google-search-console, google-index

We are facing a very strange issue where google is indexing our FTP domain `ftp.example.com`.

We do not have that as a subdomain and there is no root folder or any other files for it.

So I am not sure how to block it and make sure Google does not index it.

**Things I have tried:**

I have checked file manager and also tried to add robots and `.htaccess` file to redirect it main domain but it is not working.

Can anyone help me with it?

**New information**

We are using Control Web Portal (CWP) and not cpanel.

We added the following .htaccess rule to the root folder of main domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ftp\.exrx\.net  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://exrx.net/$1 [L]
```

But this is also not working

Comment: "tried to add robots and htaccess file to redirect it main domain" - What did you add and where exactly? And what does "not working" mean? (You cannot block a hostname in `robots.txt` (without additional URL-rewriting) - but even if you could, this would not resolve your issue once the hostname has already been indexed - it would likely just compound the problem.)

Comment: We added the following .htaccess rule to the root folder of main domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ftp\.exrx\.net  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://exrx.net/$1 [L]
```

But this is also not working

Answer (score 1):

Many hosting control panels (like cPanel, Plesk, etc.) create several subdomains automatically, including `ftp.example.com`. This is simply an alias of the main domain (there is no subdirectory that it points to) that is created as a "convenience".

If Google has picked this up then there are likely "public" links to this subdomain somewhere.

In something like cPanel, you may not be able to remove it (without perhaps disabling the FTP service)or manually editing the DNS zone. However, you can redirect requests to your main domain to resolve the indexing issue.

For example, at the top of your root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 # Redirect "ftp.example.com/<anything>" to "www.example.com/<anything>"
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ftp\.example\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You must not try and block these requests using `robots.txt` as you will just end up blocking all requests and Google won't see your redirect!

It will take a while for Google to update its index.

---

**UPDATE:**

Assuming `ftp.exrx.net` is the actual hostname in question, then it would seem the DNS entry (`CNAME` or `A` record) for this subdomain has since been removed so the hostname no longer resolves. (The DNS entry must have been present initially, otherwise the hostname would not have been indexed.)

Consequently you will not be able to implement a "redirect" to canonicalise these requests (since the request no longer reaches your server). This is arguably how it should have been configured (or "not" configured) initially. (Google obviously won't index anything that does not resolve.)

However, in order to "fix" the already indexed pages and redirect the request/user to the canonical hostname (ie. `exrx.net`) you will need to (at least temporarily) reinstate the relevant DNS entry (eg. a `CNAME` record that points to the domain apex *OR* an `A` record that points to the sever's IP address). This is assuming the server is still configured to accept requests to this hostname. If not then this will need to be reinstated also (eg. a `ServerAlias ftp.exrx.net` directive in the relevant `<VirtualHost>` container). And possibly modify your SSL cert to include the `ftp` subdomain (`ftp.exrx.net`) in the SAN field, if that has also been removed.

Comment: I have added further information in the question and replied to your comment as well

Comment: @ParthParikh It would seem this `ftp` subdomain no longer resolves - this is something you would need to "fix" first. I've updated my answer.